# Bad connection between Qnap and Mac

Tags: macos, qnap

The connection between my MacBook and the Qnap TS-112 is very poor. When I try to mount it,  it usually says "Connection failed". When it does connect it can be very slow.

The thing I want is when I open my MacBook, the Qnap disk pops up and I can continue my work.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Could you show your export settings from Qnap and how you're trying to mount it on the Mac?

Comment: I'm not sure how to export my Qnap settings? Perhaps you can explain how to do this. What I do is, when the NAS drives appears in the left bar from finder, under shared, I click the disk to connect. Very often it says "unable to connect". But the drives not always show up in the finder.

Comment: Do you have other devices for which it works well? Does the QNAP spin down its drives when idle? I have a TS-212 and sometimes it takes a minute or so to finally connect. Sometimes it also says "Item not found" or something.

Comment: This problem occurs to my Macbook Pro 15" Retina and my iMac late 2007. There is also a Mede8er Media player connected through UTP. This media-player plays movies from the NAS pretty well. The NAS is hardwired through UTP connected to my router.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I have found the problem. I did connect through IP using smb://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx. My Qnap is called SRV1. So I try to connect using smb://SRV1.

I also deleted the connection history in the "Connect to server window".

This works like a charm.
Thanks all for helping me out!

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this other superuser answer - It worked for me

[OS X: How to avoid having to re-connect to network share after NAS was turned off?](https://superuser.com/questions/300087/os-x-how-to-avoid-having-to-re-connect-to-network-share-after-nas-was-turned-of/303011#303011)

I have found that my qnap interpretation of AFP is quite odd and slow in connecting. SMB works far better if you have that protocol enabled.

Comment: Thanks, im sure it's not OS X. On my work we're running a Synology NAS. It alway connect without any problem. It's just the Qnap which causes a headache;-)